# "We was" vs. "We were" and "Be you" vs "Are you" in song lyrics

Tags: grammar, style, lyrics

Listening to an english song, I noticed the following sentences:

"We **was** hitchhiking down..." (1:15) https://youtu.be/_lK4cX5xGiQ?t=75

"**Be** you angels?" (2:36) https://youtu.be/_lK4cX5xGiQ?t=155

Why is it not:
"We **were** hitchhiking down..." and "**Are** you angels?"

Is this grammatically correct or is it more used to "style" the language in a certain way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there are two different reasons for each of the lines you quote, despite them coming from the same song.

Remember this is a *comedy* rock song - so don't take it too seriously.

> We was hitchhikin' down a long and lonesome road

You are correct that the proper grammar would be "we *were* hitchhiking...". This is an example of *colloquial* speech, imitating a particular kind of localised American dialect. This kind of language is popularised in *country music* and so I believe this is used here to invoke that kind of imagery, as parts of the song appear to be a pastiche of country music with the story-telling lyrics and acoustic guitars.

> Be you angels?

Again, you are right that this is not grammatically correct in modern English - but it is in imitation of *Old English*, or *Early Modern English*, the kind sometimes used in folklore tales. In this particular song these words are supposedly spoken to them by a demon they meet in the road. Early Modern English is the language used in the King James translation of the Bible - for example at Ephesians 4:32 the old English translation is "*be ye kind to one another*" - so I think they used it to invoke this kind of imagery.

Comment: The King James Bible is definitely not written in Old English.  It's Early Modern English.  Old English does not mean old-fashioned English, or English that's old.  It's basically a different language that was spoken from about 450 to 1150 (the King James Bible was finished in 1611).

The Lord's Prayer in the King James Bible:

Our Father which art in heaven, Hallowed be thy name. Thy kingdom come, Thy will be done in earth, as it is in heaven.

Old English:

Fæder ure þu þe eart on heofonum; Si þin nama gehalgod to becume þin rice gewurþe ðin willa on eorðan swa swa on heofonum.

Comment: @Juhasz Thank you, I have corrected the terminology in my answer. I'm sure this will help explain this comedy rock song.

Answer (score 1):

"Be you angels" is meant to invoke an older form of English from centuries past, since they're singing a ballad reminiscent of the so-called English Border Ballad.